# Unable to create key file for iam account GCP using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I am trying to create a key file for a service account on GCP with gcloud

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/.config/gcloud/key.json \
--iam-account terraform@$myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Unfortunately, it responds

```
(gcloud) Unable to create private file [~/.config/gcloud/key.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.config/gcloud/key.json'
```

The folder

```
 '~/.config/gcloud/'
```

exists.

Comment: What happens if you specify the full pathname? What is the output from `whoami`? What is the output from `ls -ld ~/.config/gcloud`?

Comment: full pathname works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is:

```
'~/.config/gcloud/'
```

this should be

```
'/home/mike/.config/gcloud/'
```

as John Hanley correctly pointed out.